# How to access apex data from sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-apex

I have setup an oracle database in my Ubuntu machine. Now I have took the following steps to create tables

1) login to my ubuntu account

2) `su oracle`

3) `sqlplus "sys as sysdba"`
//Connected to an idle instance

4) sql prompt `sql>startup`

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
```

5) in sql prompt.. `sql> exec dbms_xdb_config.sethttpport(8080);`

6) `sql> exit`

7)`lsnrctl start`

Then I have login to oracle apex in a workspace which I created earlier and created a table named  `person`

but when I again login to to sqlplus like `sqlplus "sys as sysdba"` and run the following query

`select * from person`
It says , no table created.

I am a newbie in database , so please tell me how do I access the tables I have created in apex , from sqlplus console ? It used to be so simple in 10g.

Answer (score 2):

Table `person` is situated in schema assigned to your apex workspace. You can go to APEX IDE to the section `SQL Workshop` -> `Object Browser`, schema name will be displayed in the top right part of the page. Or you can execute query:

```
select owner from all_tables
where table_name = 'PERSON';
```

You will get names of all users that have table with such name.
After that you need to use this name in your query:

```
select * from schema_name.person
```